# Wpf: How to bind SelectedItem from nested DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I don't know how to properly bind **SelectedItem** from a nested DataGrid. In the main DataGrid I have a binding like this:

```ini
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}"
```

and it work OK - if I select **element** in DataGrid property **SelectedElement** from MainVM class is set to the selected element.
I have a similar binding in the nested DataGrid:

```ini
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyItem}"
```

but it doesn't work at all - when I select **item** in nested DataGrid, property **SelectedMyItem** is still **null**.

**My question:

How do I bind the SelectedMyItem property so that it is set after selecting item in the DataGrid?**

I am not getting any bind error information from the IDE.

Here is a simple example showing my problem:

Classes:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace NesteGridMVVM
{
    public class MyItem
    {
        public string MyItemName { get; set; }
    }
    
    //======================================================================
    
    public class Element
    {
        private MyItem _selectedItem;

        public string ElementName { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItemsList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();

        //Binded to SelectedItem in nested DataGrid
        public MyItem SelectedMyItem
        {
            get => _selectedItem;
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;

                //Show, if MyItem was selected - it not work.
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"Selected MyItem: {_selectedItem.MyItemName}");
            }
        }
    }
    
    //======================================================================

    public class MainVM
    {
        private Element _selectedElement;

        public ObservableCollection<Element> ElementsList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Element>();

        //Binded to SelectedItem in main DataGrid
        public Element SelectedElement
        {
            get => _selectedElement;
            set
            {
                _selectedElement = value;

                //Show, if Element was selected - it works OK
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"{_selectedElement.ElementName}");
            }
        }

        //ctor - populate view model
        public MainVM()
        {
            Element elem1 = new Element() { ElementName = "element-01" };
            Element elem2 = new Element() { ElementName = "element-02" };

            elem1.MyItemsList.Add(new MyItem() { MyItemName = "item-A" });
            elem1.MyItemsList.Add(new MyItem() { MyItemName = "item-B" });
            elem2.MyItemsList.Add(new MyItem() { MyItemName = "item-C" });

            ElementsList.Add(elem1);
            ElementsList.Add(elem2);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```ini
<Window x:Class="NesteGridMVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NesteGridMVVM"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="600">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainVM /> 
    </Window.DataContext>

    <DataGrid
        x:Name="MainDG"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementsList}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}"
        RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid
                    x:Name="NestedDG"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsList}"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyItem}">
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you can modify the binding trigger to be on `PropertyChanged`:

`SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

However, just a note on this:

When I run this in the debugger, the nested DataGrid selection fires before the outer DataGrid.  Meaning the `set` for `SelectedMyItem` will fire before `SelectedElement`.  This is of course only when you are changing rows in the outer DataGrid.

The full `.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="NesteGridMVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NesteGridMVVM"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="600">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainVM /> 
    </Window.DataContext>

    <DataGrid
        x:Name="MainDG"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementsList}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}"
        RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid
                    x:Name="NestedDG"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsList}"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I wanted to achieve, but I don't understand exactly why adding UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged fixed the problem?

Comment: @AdamMroczek Mostly just a WPF quirk, a lot of times in `WPF` the default trigger for bindings is when you leave the field or `LostFocus`.  I am guessing the problem with the inner DataGrid is that they each have their own separate focusable that can stay "focused" even when you click on another one.  If you want an example take a `TextBox` with a default text binding - it wont trigger until you tab/click away.  Changing the trigger to PropertyChanged will make it fire as you type.