# Trouble binding selected item from nested datagrid to listbox of expanders in WPF MVVM app - any solutions?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

In my xaml I have a listbox, in this listbox I want to show expanders that show a datagrid if it is expanded. everything works except for the binding selected item from the datagrid. It wont bind to anything.

```
<ListBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Reizen}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Expander Header="{Binding Naam}" Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <DataGrid x:Name="datagridStores"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Onkosten}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding GeselecteerdeOnkost, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                IsReadOnly="True">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Bedrag, StringFormat=C, ConverterCulture=nl-BE}" Header="Bedrag"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Omschrijving}" Header="Omschrijving"/>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </Expander>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

How can I make this work?

I tried the solution from the link below, but that doesn't work for me.
[Wpf: How to bind SelectedItem from nested DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69668996/wpf-how-to-bind-selecteditem-from-nested-datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the Output of your Project when you run it. I guess there are BindingErrors.

A solution could be to provide a relative Source for the Binding of the selected item could be something like:

`SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.GeselecteerdeOnkost, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: in the output I get this error: **System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'GeselecteerdeOnkost' property not found on 'object' ''Reis' (HashCode=29544808)'. BindingExpression:Path=GeselecteerdeOnkost; DataItem='Reis' (HashCode=29544808); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')**. I found that if I put a new property in the class **Reis** with the name **GeselecteerdeOnkost** the error goes away. but I want the selectedItem to bind to a property in my viewmodel.